Rate of change of water level as it's being poured into an upright right rectangular pyramid
Water is poured into an upright pyramid at a constant rate of $24in^3/s$. The pyramid is a right rectangular pyramid with a height of $9in$ and a square base with side length $6in$.
The volume of a pyramid is given by:
$V = \frac13 * base area* height$
How fast is the water level rising when the water is $6in$ high?
I've never come across a rate of change in an upright three dimensional shape problem. I can solve a rate of change problem in inverted three dimensional shape.
My logic is that, because the shape is upright, as the water is being filled, the water forms a frustum, and the rate of change gets higher and higher.
The step I've taken to solve this is:

Calculate the volume of the frustum using the volume of the entire pyramid - the volume of the unfilled pyramid. The equation is $V=\frac13*6*6*9-\frac13*(6-\frac{2h}{3})^2*(9-h)$
This yields $V = \frac{4h^3}{27}-4h^2+36h$
Differentiate with respect to $h$. The differentiation is $\frac{dV}{dh}=\frac{4}{9}h^2-8h+36$
Setup $\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{dV}{dh}*\frac{dh}{dt}$
Substitute $\frac{dV}{dt}$ and $\frac{dV}{dh}$. It becomes $24 = (\frac{4}{9}h^2-8h+36)*\frac{dh}{dt}$
Substitute $h = 6$. It becomes $24 = (\frac{4}{9}6^2-8(6)+36)*\frac{dh}{dt}$
The result is $\frac{dh}{dt} = 6in/s$

But I'm not sure about this answer. I can't verify it because I can't find any similar problem on the internet. All the problems I've found are for an inverted shape.

Your approach is a reasonable one but more complicated than necessary.  You should recognize that the rate of rise is the rate of volume increase divided by the top area.  At the time of interest the water fills $\frac 23$ of the height, so (by similar triangles) the top of the water is $\frac 13 \cdot 6=2$ inches square, so the area is $4 in^2$  The water is then rising $\frac {24}4=6\ in/sec$
